# JAVA - replaceAll in a regex with $1

Tags: java, regex, extract

On a CodeFight problem it is asked to extract the first digits of a String and return it as a string, return null if it doesn't start with digits.

I used regex, no problem, yet I don't understand very well the top answer :

```
String longestDigitsPrefix(String inputString) {
    return inputString.replaceAll("^(\\d*).*","$1");
}
```

If somebody can explain that'd be awesome :)

Comment: Are you sure it's supposed to return `null` if it doesn't start with digits? Because the method you've posted returns the empty string `""` in that case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 9):

The regex `^(\\d*).*` always matches the *entire* input, capturing (via the brackets) the leading (the `^` means "start of input") digits (if any - the `*` means 0 or more and `\d` means "a digit")

The replacement string `$1` means "group 1" (the first group made by a set of brackets).

---

Actually, the solution given is not the most elegant. This is better/simpler/faster/more readable:

```
String longestDigitsPrefix(String inputString) {
    return inputString.replaceAll("\\D.*", "");
}
```

This regex matches from the first non-digit encountered to the end and just deletes it (replaces with nothing).

Comment: Yes the function is supposed to return null.
Thanks a lot Bohemian, actually what confused me is that I thought ^(\\d*) was the same as \\D* !
Your solution is even better ! I'm quite amazed by regex in general and how efficient it can be, but it's not super easy to master.